# How to make the imports in python in a project of several modules organised in different folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am building a software. I organised the different code in differents python files (the modules) organised in different folders.

It was working like a charm. Then today it doesn't work anymore as I have some issues:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules.mymodulesteam'
```

This is how my code is organized:

```
MySoftware/
    - start.py
    - modules/
        -- mymodules.py
        -- prepare.py
        -- mymodulesteam.py
```

In the start.py file, I have this import:

```
from modules import prepare_envir_appium
```

in prepare.py I have this line of import

```
import modules.mymodulesteam as mymodules
```

When I execute "start.py", I have this error message in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\MySoftware\modules\prepare.py",
        import modules.mymodulesteam as mymodules
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules.mymodulesteam'
```

so I search for help and I saw I had to add some _*init*.py file in my folder "modules". I did it and it didn't work. I get the exact same issue.

I read every single post regarding this kind of issue and tried much stuff.

```
from modules import mymodulesteam
from . import mymodulesteam
etc...
```

And I get this kind of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\MySoftware\modules\prepare.py",
    from modules import mymodulesteam as mymodules
ImportError: cannot import name 'mymodulesteam' from 'modules' (E:\MySoftware\modules\__init__.py)
```

So I removed this "_ *init* _.py" file and tested again. I get this error this time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\MySoftware\modules\prepare.py",
    from modules import mymodulesteam as mymodules
ImportError: cannot import name 'mymodulesteam' from 'modules' (unknown location)
```

It used to work very well. I don't know what happened. Does anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t work because the modules are not in the same path and the script doesn’t know where to look.

Your current `start.py` file looks like this,

```
from modules import prepare_envir_appium
```

Instead, do this at the top of your `start.py` file, because your `prepare_envir_appium.py` file is located in modules.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"../modules")

import prepare_envir_appium
```

Now you can access your functions using `prepare_envir_appium.functionname`.

You can also do this,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"../modules")

import prepare_envir_appium as per
```

Now you can access the functions using `per.functionname` within start.py.

You can also import specific functions like this,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"../modules")

from prepare_envir_appium import functionname1, functionname2
```

and you can just run them using their function names.

However, if you are looking at the `prepare.py` script, because the module is in the same folder as the script, all you have to do is import the file name like below without the .py extension.

You can follow the same import naming conventions as above.

```
import mymodulesteam
```

or

```
import mymodulesteam as mmt
```

or

```
from mymodulesteam import function1, function2
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Also, "import mymodules" is in the prepare.py file which is in the subfolder "modules"

Comment: @GauthierButtez for scripts in the same folder as the module, all you need to do is import the file name without .py

Comment: If it doesn’t work, can you show me the error ? @GauthierButtez

Comment: I get same kind of error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodulesteam'"

Comment: Can you delete the init.py file and show me what you get @GauthierButtez

Comment: Without __init__.py, I get this error "ImportError: cannot import name 'mymodulesteam' from 'modules' (unknown location)", with __init__.py I get this error : "ImportError: cannot import name 'mymodulesteam' from 'modules' (E:\MySoftware\modules\\__init__.py)"

Comment: Can you show me what you have typed in the import statements ?

Comment: in start.py => from modules import prepare_envir_appium, in modules\prepare.py =>from modules import mymodulesteam as mymodules

Comment: You’re not reading my thing properly, I can still see you’re using the wrong import syntax @GauthierButtez

Comment: @GauthierButtez I will change my answer again to make it clearer, please hold on and read it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239646/discussion-between-anarchy-and-gauthier-buttez).

Comment: @GauthierButtez my code helped you to fix the imports right ? Even without the usb error, you were using the wrong import statements